# Reverse a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you reverse a string in Ruby? I know about string#reverse. I'm interested in understanding how to write it in pure Ruby, preferably an in-place solution.

Comment: this is will be way slower than string#reverse btw.

Comment: @Rishav, how do you know this to be the case. What do you think is happening with the reverse?

Comment: @VoodooChild http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/String.src/M000609.html - It's very unlikely that Ruby will be able to compete with C in the speed category.

Comment: @VoodooChild string#reverse internals use C to calculate the reverse.

Comment: By "in-place solution" do you mean the equivalent of `string#reverse!`? A function that modifies the string directly rather than a duplicate?

Comment: @Rishav: I recall Jorg Mittag saying that Rubinius can do some things in pure Ruby faster than YARV does in C.

Comment: As a sidenote, `"{{{1,2,3}},{4,5,6}}".reverse` = `"}}6,5,4{,}}3,2,1{{{"`. Since it reverses brackets, it's doing more than a 'mirror'/'order' flip. It's manipulating the numbers that characters represent.

Answer (score 46):

There's already an inplace reverse method, called "reverse!":

```
$ a = "abc"
$ a.reverse!
$ puts a
cba
```

If you want to do this manually try this (but it will probably not be multibyte-safe, eg UTF-8), and it will be slower:

```
class String
  def reverse_inplace!
    half_length = self.length / 2
    half_length.times {|i| self[i], self[-i-1] = self[-i-1], self[i] }
    self
  end
end
```

This swaps every byte from the beginning with every byte from the end until both indexes meet at the center:

```
$ a = "abcd"
$ a.reverse_inplace!
$ puts a
dcba
```

Comment: It should be multibyte safe in versions of Ruby where the normal replace is, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure, the linked C source above isn't (at least not the loop). I don't know what the "single_byte_optimizable" does... BTW: The ruby version isn't multibyte safe. I just tried...

Comment: 1.9.2 should be multibyte safe. 1.8 versions will probably not be.

Comment: "This swaps every byte from the beginning with every byte from the end until both indexes meet at the center" - pre-1.9.2 that would be true, as Ruby considered characters to be equivalent to bytes. In 1.9+ they could be multiple bytes but still be a single character.

Comment: You need to return self, otherwise the length is going to be returned instead.

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing I've changed it since it makes sense

Answer (score 14):

Just for discussion, with that many alternates, it is good to see if there are major differences in speed/efficiency. I cleaned up the code a bit as the code showing output was repeatedly reversing the outputs.

```
# encoding: utf-8

require "benchmark"

reverse_proc = Proc.new { |reverse_me| reverse_me.chars.inject([]){|r,c| r.unshift c}.join }

class String
  def reverse # !> method redefined; discarding old reverse
    each_char.to_a.reverse.join
  end

  def reverse! # !> method redefined; discarding old reverse!
    replace reverse
  end

  def reverse_inplace!
    half_length = self.length / 2
    half_length.times {|i| self[i], self[-i-1] = self[-i-1], self[i] }
  end

end

def reverse(a)
  (0...(a.length/2)).each {|i| a[i], a[a.length-i-1]=a[a.length-i-1], a[i]}
  return a
end

def reverse_string(string) # method reverse_string with parameter 'string'
  loop = string.length       # int loop is equal to the string's length
  word = ''                  # this is what we will use to output the reversed word
  while loop > 0             # while loop is greater than 0, subtract loop by 1 and add the string's index of loop to 'word'
    loop -= 1                  # subtract 1 from loop
    word += string[loop]       # add the index with the int loop to word
  end                        # end while loop
  return word                # return the reversed word
end                        # end the method

lorum = <<EOT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quis magna eu
lacus pulvinar vestibulum ut ac ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et pretium orci. Phasellus congue iaculis
sollicitudin. Morbi in sapien mi, eget faucibus ipsum. Praesent pulvinar nibh
vitae sapien congue scelerisque. Aliquam sed aliquet velit. Praesent vulputate
facilisis dolor id ultricies. Phasellus ipsum justo, eleifend vel pretium nec,
pulvinar a justo. Phasellus erat velit, porta sit amet molestie non,
pellentesque a urna. Etiam at arcu lorem, non gravida leo. Suspendisse eu leo
nibh. Mauris ut diam eu lorem fringilla commodo. Aliquam at augue velit, id
viverra nunc.
EOT
```

And the results:

```
RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.2"

name = "Marc-André"; reverse_proc.call(name) # => "érdnA-craM"
name = "Marc-André"; name.reverse! # => "érdnA-craM"
name = "Marc-André"; name.chars.inject([]){|s, c| s.unshift(c)}.join # => "érdnA-craM"
name = "Marc-André"; name.reverse_inplace!; name # => "érdnA-craM"
name = "Marc-André"; reverse(name) # => "érdnA-craM"
name = "Marc-André"; reverse_string(name) # => "érdnA-craM"

n = 5_000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("1:") { n.times do; reverse_proc.call(lorum); end }
  x.report("2:") { n.times do; lorum.reverse!; end }
  x.report("3:") { n.times do; lorum.chars.inject([]){|s, c| s.unshift(c)}.join; end }
  x.report("4:") { n.times do; lorum.reverse_inplace!; end }
  x.report("5:") { n.times do; reverse(lorum); end }
  x.report("6:") { n.times do; reverse_string(lorum); end }
end

# >>              user     system      total        real
# >> 1:       4.540000   0.000000   4.540000 (  4.539138)
# >> 2:       2.080000   0.010000   2.090000 (  2.084456)
# >> 3:       4.530000   0.010000   4.540000 (  4.532124)
# >> 4:       7.010000   0.000000   7.010000 (  7.015833)
# >> 5:       5.660000   0.010000   5.670000 (  5.665812)
# >> 6:       3.990000   0.030000   4.020000 (  4.021468)
```

It's interesting to me that the "C" version ("reverse_string()") is the fastest pure-Ruby version. #2 ("reverse!") is fastest but it's taking advantage of the `[].reverse`, which is in C.

- Edit by Marc-André Lafortune *

Adding an extra test case (7):

```
def alt_reverse(string)
  word = ""
  chars = string.each_char.to_a
  chars.size.times{word << chars.pop}
  word
end
```

If the string is longer (`lorum *= 10, n/=10`), we can see that the difference widens because some functions are in O(n^2) while others (mine :-) are O(n):

```
             user     system      total        real
1:      10.500000   0.030000  10.530000 ( 10.524751)
2:       0.960000   0.000000   0.960000 (  0.954972)
3:      10.630000   0.080000  10.710000 ( 10.721388)
4:       6.210000   0.060000   6.270000 (  6.277207)
5:       4.210000   0.070000   4.280000 (  4.268857)
6:      10.470000   3.540000  14.010000 ( 15.012420)
7:       1.600000   0.010000   1.610000 (  1.601219)
```

Comment: Nice test. Do `lorum *= 10, n /= 10` and the results will show you that any solution using `[]` is not of the right order (i.e. O(n^2)) instead of O(n) for solutions with `each_char`. Also, using `+=` like #6 also gives you #6. I edited my answer with another solution not using `reverse`.

Comment: I meant "also gives you O(n^2)"

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, Good points. Feel free to edit and append the tests with your changes since you've got the reputation. :-)

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, I attempted to replicate some of your benchmarks using ruby `2.2.0`, but didn't get the divergence in speed you showed here.   Specifically, it didn't seem like the reverse with `#unshift` was running O(n^2).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JamieB Ruby now [optimizes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/fdbd3716781817c8) for successive unshifts and pre allocates some memory to avoid moving all elements.

Answer (score 9):

The Ruby equivalent of the builtin `reverse` could look like:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class String
  def reverse
    each_char.to_a.reverse.join
  end

  def reverse!
    replace reverse
  end
end

str = "Marc-André"
str.reverse!
str # => "érdnA-craM"
str.reverse # => "Marc-André"
```

*Note*: this assumes Ruby 1.9, or else `require "backports"` and set `$KCODE` for UTF-8.

For a solution not involving `reverse`, one could do:

```
def alt_reverse(string)
  word = ""
  chars = string.each_char.to_a
  chars.size.times{word << chars.pop}
  word
end
```

Note: any solution using `[]` to access individual letters will be of order `O(n^2)`; to access the 1000th letter, Ruby must go through the first 999 one by one to check for multibyte characters. It is thus important to use an iterator like `each_char` for a solution in `O(n)`.

Another thing to avoid is to build intermediate values of increasing length; using `+=` instead of `<<` in `alt_reverse` would also make the solution `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`.

Building an array with `unshift` will also make the solution `O(n^2)`, because it implies recopying all existing elements one index higher each time one does an `unshift`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it with inject and unshift:

```
"Hello world".chars.inject([]) { |s, c| s.unshift(c) }.join
```

Comment: Note that using `unshift` makes your solution O(n^2). See my solutions for O(n).

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "something"
reverse = ""
str.length.times do |i|
  reverse.insert(i, str[-1-i].chr)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"abcde".chars.reduce{|s,c| c + s }          # => "edcba"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
def reverse_string(string) # Method reverse_string with parameter 'string'.
  loop = string.length # int loop is equal to the string's length.
  word = '' # This is what we will use to output the reversed word.
  while loop > 0 # while loop is greater than 0, subtract loop by 1 and add the string's index of loop to 'word'.
    loop -= 1 # Subtract 1 from loop.
    word += string[loop] # Add the index with the int loop to word.
  end # End while loop.
  return word # Return the reversed word.
end # End the method.
```

Comment: Downvoting because this is writing C in Ruby.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I decided to leave this answer as posted just incase anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

```
def reverse(string)
  result = ""
  idx = string.length - 1
  while idx >= 0
  result << string [idx]
  idx = idx - 1
 end

 result

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See the [how to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: Please explain more in detail about your answer and what it is doing. Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution described below. There is no need to go beyond the half of array size:

```
class ReverseString

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
    @size  = @array.size
  end

  def process
    (0...@size/2).to_a.each_with_index do |e,i|
      @array[i], @array[@size-i-1] = @array[@size-i-1], @array[i]
    end
    @array
  end

end


require 'minitest/autorun'

class ReverseStringTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_process
    assert_equal "9876543210", ReverseString.new("0123456789").process
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that made the most sense to me as a ruby beginner

```
def reverse(string)
  reversed_string = ''

  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    reversed_string = string[i] + reversed_string
    i += 1
  end

  reversed_string
end

p reverse("helter skelter")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to read one-liner,

```
def reverse(a)
    (0...(a.length/2)).each {|i| a[i], a[a.length-i-1]=a[a.length-i-1], a[i]}
    return a
end
```

Comment: Not multibyte aware... BTW, the two last `a.length` can be removed

Comment: he didn't ask for pretty code, guys—this doesn't deserve a -1.

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune, please explain why it is not multi-byte aware. It uses all multibyte-sensitive calls.

Comment: @the Tin Man: I meant it is not multibyte aware in Ruby 1.8: with $KCODE = "U", any multi-byte character will not reverse properly. In Ruby 1.9 it works fine.

Comment: OK, and yes. < 1.9 there'd be problems with multibyte chars.

Answer (score 1):

Also, using Procs ...

```
Proc.new {|reverse_me| reverse_me.chars.inject([]){|r,c| r.unshift c}.join}.call("The house is blue")

=> "eulb si esuoh ehT"
```

Proc.new would be handy here because you could then nest your reversing algorithm (and still keep things on one line).  This would be handy if, for instance, you needed to reverse each word in an already-reversed sentence:

```
# Define your reversing algorithm
reverser = Proc.new{|rev_me| rev_me.chars.inject([]){r,c| r.unshift c}.join}

# Run it twice - first on the entire sentence, then on each word
reverser.call("The house is blue").split.map {|w| reverser.call(w)}.join(' ')

=> "blue is house The"
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at how Rubinius implements the method - they implement much of the core library in Ruby itself, and I wouldn't be surprised if `String#reverse` and `String#reverse!` is implemented in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(string)

  s = string.gsub(/\W+/,'').downcase

  t = s.chars.inject([]){|a,b| a.unshift(b)}.join

  return true if(s == t)

  false

end
```

Comment: what does inject([]) do?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sentence "The greatest victory is that" and you want to have "that is victory greatest The" you should to use this method

```
def solution(sentance)
  sentance.split.reverse.join(" ")
end

solution("The greatest victory is that")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using the xor bitwise operations:

```
class String

  def xor_reverse
    len = self.length - 1
    count = 0

    while (count < len)
      self[count] ^= self[len]
      self[len] ^= self[count]
      self[count] ^= self[len]

      count += 1
      len -= 1
    end

  self
end

"foobar".xor_reverse
=> raboof
```

Comment: btw, this won't work in 1.9 since the behavior of "a"[0] changed.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby:

```ruby
name = "Hello World"; reverse_proc.call(name) 

name = "Hello World"; name.reverse! 

name = "Hello World"; name.chars.inject([]){|s, c| s.unshift(c)}.join 

name = "Hello World"; name.reverse_inplace!; 

name = "Hello World"; reverse(name) 

name = "Hello World"; reverse_string(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work also

```
def reverse(str)
  string = ''
   (0..str.size-1).each do |i|
    string << str[str.size - 1 - i]
   end
  string
end
```

Comment: Wild or educated guess?

Comment: Sorry thanks for pointing out my mistake, I've now corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(string)
reversed_string = ""

idx = 0
while idx < string.length
reversed_string = string[idx] + reversed_string
idx += 1
end

return reversed_string
end
```

Comment: While this is not an "in-place" solution, it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "This is my string"
string_arr = string.split('')
n = string_arr.length
new_arr = Array.new

17.times do |i|
  new_arr << string_arr.values_at(n - i)
end

reversed_string = new_arr.flatten.join('')
=> "gnirts ym si sihT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple alternative, it first breaks the string into an array, counts the length and subtracts one(because of ruby's indexing rule for array starting from 0), creates an empty variable, then runs an iteration on the keys of the array whilst appending the value of the array length minus current array index to the empty variable created and when it reaches the zeroth(sorry for my french) value it stops. Hope this helps.

```
class String
   def rString
       arr = self.split("")
       len = arr.count - 1
       final = ""
       arr.each_index do |i|
           final += arr[len - i]
       end
       final
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple classic way with n/2 complexity

```
str = "Hello World!";
puts str;

for i in 0..(str.length/2).to_i
  mid = (str.length-1-i);
  temp = str[i];
  str[i] = str[aa];
  str[aa] = temp;
end

puts str;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

we can use **inject** method to make it simple:

```
def reverse_str(str)
  (1..str.length).inject('') {|rev_str, i| rev_str.concat(str[str.length-i])}
end
```

**Note:** I have used `concat` instead `+=` because concat will change the string into same reference but += will create new object

for example

```
str = 'sanjay' #object.id #69080

str.concat('choudhary') #object.id #69080 #look here object id is same

str += 'choudhary' #object.id #78909 #look here object id will change.
```