# how is the string reverse function implemented in ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse a string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057967/reverse-a-string-in-ruby)

in python using **extended slice** , an implementation for string **reverse** can be written like this

```
>>> 'hello world'[::-1]
'dlrow olleh'
```

i wonder how would one implement string **reverse** function in Ruby

Comment: Why are you looking for another way to do it in Ruby? In ruby, there is One True Way to do a reverse.

Comment: how is the ruby reverse function implemented ??

Comment: @JouniK.Seppänen all those solutions are not as elegant as this python snippet

Comment: @vireshas You have a funny definition for [elegant](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aelegant). The python slice may be ingenious, but it is not simple, graceful, or stylishly expressive compared to [String#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-reverse). If you want to know how reverse is implemented, go to that prior link and click 'toggle source'.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> "Hello world".reverse
=> "dlrow olleH"
```