# Convert a string to an array and reverse it

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert a string into an array and then reverse it using `Enumerable#each`. In the following, I expect to get `["k","o","o","b"]`.

```
def reverse(string)
  array = string.split("")
  reverse_array = []
  i = array.length - 1
  array.each do |letter|
    reverse_array << letter[i]
    i = i - 1
    break if i == -1
  end
  p reverse_array
end

reverse("book") # => [nil, nil, nil, "k"]
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting `nil`, and how I would fix the code using `Enumerable#each`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057967/reverse-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: The problem is with the line `reverse_array << letter[i]`. The variable letter holds a single letter, not an array, so just get rid of `[i]`.

Comment: While getting rid of `[i]`: get rid of lines 4, 7 and 8 too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `string` is `"book"`. So, `array = string.split("")` is `["b", "o", "o", "k"]`. Then you iterate with `i`, starting with non-`0`, decrementing to `0`. Since the element strings all have length `1`, `letter[i]` will return the string itself when `i` is `0`, and `nil` otherwise. That gives you `reverse_array` to be `[nil, nil, nil, "k"]`.

A fix would be replacing:

```
reverse_array << letter[i]
```

with:

```
reverse_array << letter
```