# Is there a way in Ruby to reverse a string like Python slicing?

Tags: python, ruby, string, slice, reverse

Python does have a slicing operator to reverse a string or list.

Example:

```
"foobar"[::-1]   # raboof
```

Is there such a way exist in Ruby where we can step in reverse order ?

**EDIT:**  I am not looking for a string reverse solution using Ruby `reverse` or `reverse!` or any other logic. I only wanted to know if there is any slicing operator exists in Ruby like Python.
So it is not duplicate of [String Reverse Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057967/reverse-a-string-in-ruby) .

Any insight about this in Ruby would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ruby strings have a `slice` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-slice), which is aliased as `[]`.It is used to slice a string in various ways. It can not be used to reverse a string however. To reverse a string use its `reverse` method

Comment: Doesn't look like you can reverse a string by slicing. There are [quite a few options](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/slice) but providing a range where the upper boundary is before the lower boundary will result in `""` (empty string) being returned.

Comment: @ulferts yes, exactly negative offeset returns `""` when we do something like this `"foobar".[-1..3]` and seems there is no way to have a `step` counter to move in reverse direction.

Comment: @dp7 What is the use case that `reverse` can't deal with? Why do you insist on slicing (especially if it is clear it does not do the same thing as in Python)?

Comment: Can we reverse a string `hello` to return a string compose of even positioned characters i.e `olh` using `reverse` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reverse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/reverse) method in ruby:

```
"foobar".reverse #=> "raboof"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was not looking for a string reverse solution using `reverse` method rather I was interested to know if there is any slicing operator in Ruby like Python. I could not find that answer after searching, so asked this question.